# How to change uipickerview in landscape?

Tags: iphone, uipickerview

Here i developing application. I could not change pickerview in landscape mode. Here is my code.

```
  -(IBAction) showPicker:(UIControl *)sender
   {
UIActionSheet *menu = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@""
                                                  delegate:self
                                         cancelButtonTitle:@"Done"
                                    destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                                         otherButtonTitles:nil];
menu.tag=1;

UIPickerView *pickerView;
if (self.interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft ||
    self.interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
{      

    pickerView = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(-80,70,220,0)];
    pickerView.delegate = self;
    pickerView.dataSource = self;
    pickerView.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;    

    [menu addSubview:pickerView];

    [menu showInView:self.view.superview];

    [menu setBounds:CGRectMake(0,0,320, 470)];

    [pickerView release]; 
    [menu release]; 

    NSLog(@"Landscape");
}
else 
{
    NSLog(@"Portrait");
    pickerView = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,70,220,0)];
    pickerView.delegate = self;
    pickerView.dataSource = self;
    pickerView.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;    

    [menu addSubview:pickerView];

    [menu showInView:self.view.superview];

    [menu setBounds:CGRectMake(0,0,320, 470)];

    [pickerView release]; 
    [menu release]; 

}
 }


 - (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component 
{
return [arrayNo count];

}
- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView {
return 1;
[entered2 resignFirstResponder];
}
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
entered2.text=[arrayNo objectAtIndex:row];
[entered2 resignFirstResponder];
}
- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component 
{
return [arrayNo objectAtIndex:row];
}
 - (CGFloat)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView widthForComponent:(NSInteger)component     
{
int sectionWidth = 300;
return sectionWidth;
}
```

In my application i created portrait mode ran fine. But when i try to write code in landscape mode it can positioned wrongly. How can i do this.
How can i change landscape mode. Anybody help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I had problems with a picker in landscape mode, and resolved it with this stackoverflow post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1088163/loading-a-uidatepicker-in-landscape-on-a-uinavigationcontroller  See if that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to set size inspector attributes like this:

[image]

P.S. **Edit 1**:You have to return yes in

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation

{
return YES;
 }
```

**Edit 2:**

If you are doing like this you don't need if condition for checking orientation and make frame for it.

Comment: Do not follow this answer or your (iPad) app is likely to get rejected. Apple's HIG clearly states that you should not change the appearance of the UIPickerView this way (trust me, i have done it and got rejected). Instead think about presenting the UIPickerView within a UIPopover on the iPad.

Comment: @Till: you may be right..But its inbuilt property in Xcode..I am not modifying PickerView..You maybe right..If its really going to get app rejected I'll delete this answer.. :-))

Comment: @Unknown : You may follow my answer..I don't think there is anything wrong..As we can increase/decrease the width of PickerView..